# How to call a function only after *ngFor finished loading?

Tags: angular, angular6

How to call a function after `*ngFor` finished loading elements in the view from an array that is  loaded from a rest api ? Putting it in the `ngAfterViewInit()` hook won't do as adding a breakpoint there shows that the `*ngFor` didn't load anything yet when the breakpoint is hit.

Comment: do you have image inside your loop elements ? if yes, your callback worry about this loading ?

Comment: @Yanis-git I have images, I don't mind about them loading later.

Comment: alright, so @bambam linked topic should do the expected job :) if not don't hesitate to tell us and updating your post, we will do our best to find solution

Comment: @Yanis-git it's true that it works, I didn't understand the syntax of the ViewChildren decorator but it worked anyway thanks